# Pkg.update() not working

Tags: julia

The below text is copied from my terminal:

```
julia> Pkg.update()
```

**INFO: Updating METADATA...**

`ERROR: METADATA cannot be updated. Resolve problems manually in /home/administrator/.julia/v0.6/METADATA`.

```
GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:SSL, SSL error: ffffffff - UNKNOWN ERROR CODE (0001))
```

Comment: julia 0.6 is no longer supported so it is probable that this issue might never be resolved. you should upgrade to the latest long term release or the latest release